# Marker Label With Map Intent

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, i want to open google map with specific location provided along with marker and its label with it. And i want to do this with 'Intent', not with 'Google Map' and 'Marker' classes. I am using the following code :

```
 post_url.setOnClickListener({
        val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/place/University+of+Oxford/@51.7548164,-1.2565555,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x4876c6a9ef8c485b:0xd2ff1883a001afed!2sUniversity+of+Oxford!8m2!3d51.7548164!4d-1.2543668!3m4!1s0x4876c6a9ef8c485b:0xd2ff1883a001afed!8m2!3d51.7548164!4d-1.2543668")
        startActivity(intent)
    })
```

It points to the provided location,but marker is not shown. I have also tried the following code:

```
post_url.setOnClickListener({
        val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=51.7548164,-1.2565555(Oxford University)")
        startActivity(intent)
    })
```

In second method marker is visible but the label is not shown.The text 'Oxford university' is written on the bottom of map with info. But i want show with marker.See the following image to understand what i want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try the other options available for launching a google map using intent.

```
Double myLatitude = 51.7548164;
Double myLongitude = -1.2565555;
String labelLocation = "Oxford university";
```

1.

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ myLatitude  +"," + myLongitude +"("+ labelLocation + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es";     
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
startActivity(intent);
```

2.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">?q=<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">(" + labelLocation + ")"));
startActivity(intent);
```

3.

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=500x500&location=" + myLatitude  + "," + myLongitude + "&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
startActivity(intent);
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have updated my question for better understand what  i want

Comment: 2 and 4 are broken since some time, despite being documented. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129726279

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String address = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ LATITUDE  +"," + LONGITUDE +"("+ YOUR-LABEL-HERE + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es";     
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(address));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Give it you lat and long and the label.

> Another answer

```
Uri gUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=YOUR_LAT,YOUR_LONG(YOUR_LABEL_HERE)");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what does this means? '&iwloc=A&hl=es'

Comment: Google Maps params, please learn about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: i could not find these params in this link

Comment: Your second solution is same as i have written.